# Working with API's in Node, security of var

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm a php developer learning how to work with Node.

When you work with php and a private API which requires an API key, you're kind of safe since you can't view PHP code in the developers console.

But now I'm working with an API in Node which has this structure.

```
var AdwordsUser = require('node-adwords-es5');

var user = new AdwordsUser({
    developerToken: 'INSERT DEVELOPER TOKEN', //your adwords developerToken 
    userAgent: 'Geen', //any company name 
    clientCustomerId: 'INSERT CLIENT ID', //the Adwords Account id (e.g. 123-123-123) 
    client_id: 'INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID_HERE', //this is the api console client_id 
    client_secret: 'INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE',
    refresh_token: 'INSERT_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE'
});
```

Since this is JavaScript I assume you will be able to see all of this in the developers console. Which is not safe?

How do people usually solve this, or am I worrying for nothing?

Comment: I don't think you can see node js code in the console. AFAIK. Node is server side

Comment: Node runs on the server, not the client. You can only see client-side javascript in the developer console.

Comment: Aah I see, makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node runs on server side so its not possible to view it in the web console. you can only view the data coming from node server on HTTP or socket call.so relax and happy coding .